# Salesforces OAuth redirecting me to Login Screen

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to create a lead on Salesforce from a form.
We do not want to use web to lead.

I can connect just fine to sales force.  After submitting the form it brings everyone to the Salesforce login screen for authentication.  It should not be doing that because we our ip is whitelisted with Salesforce and we are  supplying the username and password.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$auth_url = LOGIN_URI
    . "/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id="
    . CLIENT_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . REDIRECT_URI
    . "&username=" . USERNAME . "&password=" .  PASSWORD;

header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
?>
```